# Why is VSCode not able to read from files in the same directory as the opened file?

Tags: c++, file, visual-studio-code, ifstream

I have searched this up and tried multiple launch.json and tasks.json configurations and nothing seems to work. The program that I wrote in c++ works when I read from console, so the issue isn't with the original code. I have tried with multiple programs and never have I been able to get it to read from a file. I was hoping you could help.
This is my launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
        {
          "name": "C/C++: gcc.exe build and debug active file",
          "type": "cppdbg",
          "request": "launch",
          "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
          "args": [],
          "stopAtEntry": false,
          "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
          "environment": [],
          "externalConsole": false,
          "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        },
       ],
     
      }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
      }
```

And this is my tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\CodeBlocks\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\Program Files\\CodeBlocks\\MinGW\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

For example, a file "bac.in" contains the numbers `1 7 2 1 1 2 1 7 2`.
When running this program, the console shows 0 instead of 144:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream fin("bac.in");
int a[10];

int main()
{ 
    int S=0, i;
    while ( fin >> i )
    {
        if ( a[i] == 0 )
        {
            a[i]= 1;
            S += 10;
        }
        S += i*i;
    }
    cout << S;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"cwd": "${fileDirname}",` should have handled that.

Comment: OT: you should do yourself a favor and indent your code properly, for example like the samples in your C++ text book.

Comment: Don't use global variables. Always check for errors.

Comment: OT: It's odd that your `tasks.json` and `launch.json` mention 2 different MinGW compilers.

Comment: Maybe `bac.in` is not in the same folder as your executable. Maybe you have "hide extensions for known types" enabled in your OS file explorer and you actually created `bac.in.txt` instead and your file explorer is hiding that from you causing the problem and confusion. If you have that default setting enabled I recommend turning it off because it will likely cause you some confusion with files in c++.

Comment: @drescherjm I created the file directly in VS Code so that shouldn't be a problem. I have also tried putting .txt instead of .in and it didn't work.

Comment: Look at the folder contents in the terminal. Also verify the file contents. Perhaps you did not save it.

Comment: @drescherjm how do I look at the folder contents in the terminal? The file is saved and contains what is should.

Comment: Type `ls` or `dir` in the terminal and press enter.

Comment: @drescherjm both the .cpp file and the bac.in file are in the same folder. I genuinely don't know what to do because, as you said, "cwd": "${fileDirname}" should have taken care of that. And again, the initial program works with console given numbers so it should only be the file reading part that causes problems.

Comment: If `bac.in` is in the correct folder perhaps it does not have the contents that  you expect. Did you make sure you saved the file because VSCode will not save a file by default after an edit.

Comment: @drescherjm I made sure it was saved but I just found out I get this error in the Debug Console: `ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.`

Comment: `0xc0000135` represents a dll not found problem. Check your system `PATH` environment variable. Also you may want to make sure only 1 of the two MinGW installs are in your `PATH`

Comment: @drescherjm Hey I gave up last night and now that I reopened my PC it somehow works as expected and without any debugging errors. Maybe I had installed something that needed a restart and I just wasn't aware of it. Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: I don't have a good explanation for that. I am glad it works however.